# Linux Ubuntu 14.00 - Apache2 file not found error - where file exists

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I am using VPS with installed Ubuntu 14 OS.
Also i installed apache2 and PHP5, more info about everything installed i think you can see here: http://www.crankpost.com/phpinfo.php

I have very strange problem.
When i transfered my website from the old hosting to the VPS i started to receive strange error.

The problem is that it says that file post.php is missing when actually it's not.

I've created the phpinfo.php and as you can see you can open it. The file phpinfo.php is right next to post.php but post.php can't be opened.

Try yourself: rankpost.com/post.php <- You can't open it.

The file permission for post.php are just the same as phpinfo.php 644.

I downloaded the website with FileZilla and uploaded it to the new hosting VPS with WinSCP if it matters. Maybe someting with the transfer method ?

Can you please help me to resolve this strange problem ?

EDIT:

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^crankpost.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.crankpost.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^home mhome.php
 RewriteRule ^checklogin clogin.php 
 RewriteRule ^login login.php  
 RewriteRule ^logout log-out.php 
 RewriteRule ^registration createacc.php  
 RewriteRule ^create-account register.php  
 RewriteRule ^confirm-email=([^/.]+)?$ activateacc.php?id=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^profile=([^/.]+)?$ member.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Here is the content of post.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE Name LIKE '%" .$queryString . "%' LIMIT 10");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                $Name = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Name']); 
                    echo '<a href="# "onClick="fill(\''.$Name.'\');">'.$Name.'</a>';
                }


            } else {
                ?>
                <div style="display:block;line-height:35px;color:black;">
                    <?PHP echo NORESULT;?>
                </div>  
                <?
            }
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
```

And when it hold this content the file is not opening but if i change the content to something more simple like this:

```
if(1 == 1) {echo "HI";}
else{
echo "Bye";
}
```

With this content it's opening normal.
What is going on !?!?

I really don't know what is hapening...

Am i missing some library ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post post.php? Which way did you transfer the file(ASCII/BINARY). From which OS and php version are you coming?

Comment: The old hosting was using Linux, and i uploaded the files in BINARY.

Comment: You can open post.php but it appears to be empty, can you confirm that it is containing data? (with nano /path/to/file/post.php)

Comment: Any .htaccess rules rerouting your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mysql_` function which is deprecated since php 5.5. So you will need to change this, your file isn't usable with your installed version of php 5.5.

That's where the error comes from

Have a look on mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: Here is the phpinfo file on the old hosting so you can check which PHP version is used on the old one. https://www.youbale.com/phpinfo.php How i can downgrade my PHP version to the one used in my old hosting so i make everything worked on the old hosting work here as well ? Thanks!

Comment: You can find something about downgrading here http://askubuntu.com/questions/455614/downgrade-php-version-from-5-5-to-5-4-on-ubuntu-14-04
But instead of downgrading you should just change your files to modern sql statements, might be easier...

Comment: You mean i should change all mysql_ to mysqli_ ? and that's it ?

Comment: It's not only the 'i' you need to add, of course you need to use proper mysqli_ functions. You can have a look here: http://codular.com/php-mysqli for what needs to be changed. You should absolutely not downgrade php, you will never be able to upgrade php if you don't change your code. 
Please mark the answer as correct, thank you!

Comment: And i am pretty sure it's not the problem. Because i use all these and much more functions in my index.php file which is opening correctly...

Comment: Can you please edit this file with the correct functions for PHP5.5 so i can test it ?

Comment: No, sorry. But you can find everything in the tutorial. I've posted the link!